# A journey to find me

Tags: cipher, imgur-maze

The task is to find a word which is mostly used as a symbol in Math and Physics. It is also a giant in space.

Find the appropriate links from the below hints. The links (imgur- pages) will further provide hints to find that word.

For Prefix:

> You need to abbreviate, that is megabits are four in Roman but 5 in Arabic...

For Infix:

> Insurance Information Bureau has got a quick win by a collaboration with the Kansas City Chiefs

For Suffix:

> Do you know, egg completed an Enterprise Content Management course last Orange day ?

As an illustration, we need to find the next term of the below pattern,

> $gaM6eOI, eyK4cMG, cwI2aKE, ......$

Here the alphabets and numbers are shifted by $2$ in back. So the next term is,

$$auG0yIC$$

which leads to the following [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHuJV.jpg).

Comment: imgurmaze tag maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefix found by Omega Krypton already

> **e**

Infix

> **I**nsurance **I**nformation **B**ureau has got a **q**uick **w**in by a collaboration with the **K**ansas City **C**hiefs
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N48g.jpg
>  [image]
>  *pressure* can be measured in **psi** which is a *greek* letter

Suffix

> Do you know, **e**gg completed an **E**nterprise **C**ontent **M**anagement course **l**ast **O**range **d**ay ?
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z7mW.jpg
>  [image]
>  The city is *London*, strike a *don* leaves **lon**

The answer is

> e-psi-lon = [epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon)
>  The giant in space may be the [Epsilon Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_(rocket))

Comment: Excellent!!!...

Comment: @Ak19 Ok, yours is bigger than mine.

Answer (score 4):

Prefix:

> **e**: end of every lif**e**; beginning of every **e**nd
>  from [**https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivJTG.jpg**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivJTG.jpg): ie(that is) + Megabits(Mb) + Roman 4(iv) + Arabic 5 (5)
> [image]

Infix:

> [IIB](https://www.insuranceinformation-bureau.com/) + ... + KC (thanks @Duck!)?

Comment: Kansas City Chiefs abbreviates to KC...